# Excel/Google Sheets Transpose Column into Row Headers

Tags: excel, google-sheets, transpose

I have a large amount of website page view data. The exported format is:

```
Page    | Date (mm/yy) | View Count
-----------------------------------                                                                
Page 1  | 01/18        | 150                                
Page 1  | 02/18        | 250                                
Page 1  | 03/18        | 350                                
Page 1  | 04/18        | 450
Page 2  | 01/18        | 150                                
Page 2  | 02/18        | 250                                
Page 2  | 03/18        | 350                                
Page 2  | 04/18        | 450
```

What I would like to do is format the data like this:

```
Page    | 01/18 | 02/18
-----------------------
Page 1  | 150   | 250                                
Page 2  | 150   | 250                                
Page 3  | 150   | 250                                
Page 4  | 150   | 250
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after can be done with a Pivot table with a few clicks.

[image]

Best practice in Excel:

- turn your source data into an Excel Table object with Ctrl-T or Insert > Table
- with a cell in the table selected, use Insert > Pivot Table
- drag the page into the Rows area
- drag the date into the Rolumns area
- drag the View Count into the Values area

With an Excel Table as the source, when you add more data to your source, you can simply click a cell in the pivot table and use Data > Refresh All to, well, refresh the pivot table.

Just a few clicks, no formulas.

Answer (score 1):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

`=query({A:C}, "select Col1, sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2")`

- `pivot` does what you wanted